# Loading custom dataset in pytorch

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

Normally, when we are loading data in pytorch, we do the followings

```
for x, y in dataloaders:
    # Do something
```

However, in this dataset called [MusicNet](https://github.com/jthickstun/pytorch_musicnet/blob/master/musicnet_functional.ipynb), they declare their own dataset and dataloader like this

```
train_set = musicnet.MusicNet(root=root, train=True, download=True, window=window)#, pitch_shift=5, jitter=.1)
test_set = musicnet.MusicNet(root=root, train=False, window=window, epoch_size=50000)

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=train_set,batch_size=batch_size,**kwargs)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=test_set,batch_size=batch_size,**kwargs)
```

Then they load the data like this

```
with train_set, test_set:
    for i, (x, y) in enumerate(train_loader):
        # Do something
```

### Question 1

I don't understand why the code doesn't work without the line `with train_set, test_set`.

### Question 2

Also, how do I access the data?

I tried

```
train_set.access(2560,0)
```

and

```
with train_set, test_set:
    x, y = train_set.access(2560,0)
```

They either give me an error message like

> KeyError Traceback (most recent call last) in
>   ----> 1 train_set.access(2560,0)
>
> /workspace/raven_data/AMT/MusicNet/pytorch_musicnet/musicnet.py in
>   access(self, rec_id, s, shift, jitter) 106 107 if self.mmap:
>   --> 108 x = np.frombuffer(self.records[rec_id][0][ssz_float:int(s+scaleself.window)*sz_float],
>   dtype=np.float32).copy() 109 else: 110 fid,_ = self.records[rec_id]
>
> KeyError: 2560

or giving me an empty `x` and `y`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question 1
>
> I don't understand why the code doesn't work without the line `with train_set, test_set`.

For you to be able to use the [`torch.utils.data.DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader) with a *custom* dataset design, you *must* create a class of your dataset which subclasses [`torch.utils.data.Dataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Dataset) *(and implementing specific functions)* and pass it to the dataloader, even they say so:

> All other datasets should subclass it. All subclasses should override `__len__`, that provides the size of the dataset, and `__getitem__`, supporting integer indexing in range from 0 to len(self) exclusive.

This is what happens in:

```
train_set = musicnet.MusicNet(root=root, train=True, download=True, window=window)#, pitch_shift=5, jitter=.1)

test_set = musicnet.MusicNet(root=root, train=False, window=window, epoch_size=50000)

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=train_set,batch_size=batch_size,**kwargs)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=test_set,batch_size=batch_size,**k
```

If you check their [`musicnet.MusicNet`](https://github.com/jthickstun/pytorch_musicnet/blob/3e53fcc39cc4931bc8b7acddc326d3cfabda649f/musicnet.py#L18-L234), you will find that they do so.

> Question 2
>
> Also, how do I access the data?

There are possible ways:

To get *only* a batch from the dataset, you can do:

```
batch = next(iter(train_loader))
```

To access the whole dataset *(especially, in your example)*:

```
dataset = train_loader.dataset.records
```

(The `.records` is the part which may vary from dataset to another, I said `.records` because this is what I found in [here](https://github.com/jthickstun/pytorch_musicnet/blob/3e53fcc39cc4931bc8b7acddc326d3cfabda649f/musicnet.py#L69))